# Source for RVIZ_Plugin_Tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Title says it all, I've been googling and have been unable t find the actual source code. Where's the documentation for this?

With a catkin example CMakeLists.txt file if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233312/source-for-rviz_plugin_tutorials/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Searching for `rviz plugin tutorials` on Google gets me to [wiki.ros.org/rviz_plugin_tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_plugin_tutorials), which then under *Package Summary* has a link to [github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials) where [rviz_plugin_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/tree/kinetic-devel/rviz_plugin_tutorials) is one of the sub directories.

Make sure to select the correct branch, some things have changed (especially with how rviz handles / links to plugins).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1